# How to count total number of current touches?

Tags: touch, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to know the total number of touches we currently have globally in an app? What I do now is a workaround: I have an integer, which get increased on every "onTouchBegan" and is decreased on every "End". But the problem is that this method is not exact. If you touch the screen in a chaotic manner, this "counter" skips some touch ends...

Comment: How exact do you need it to be? If you have the touchstate in the app itself, you can combine these states in the back for every time interval.

Comment: How about decreasing count on `onTouchCancelled` ? It might be `onTouchCancelled` is called instead of `onTouchEnded`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use onTouchesBegan? Its argument is a vector of touches in the screen currently. (In case of multitouch)

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x Multitouch enabled app size of "std::vector &touches" is the number of touches.